# WatiN test cannot find element by class

Tags: c#, watin

What I've got in my HTML is:

```html
<span class="class1 class2"></span>
```

I'm trying to confirm existence of this span using the following method:

```
public bool HasSpan(string @class)
{
    return _ie.Span(Find.ByClass(@class)).Exists;
}
```

I have tried passing to the method different string values: "class1", "class2" "class1 class2" and "class2 class1", but nothing seems to work - my test cannot find the element even though it is there.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
Span sp = _ie.Span(Find.ByClass(p => p.Contains("class1")));
```

If you pass a string to the method `ByClass` (or any other method for that matter) you are searching for that exact string inside the Class attribute on the element, but if you use one of the overloaded methods, for example the one I'm using on the code above, you can have more flexibility on different scenarios, like the one you were asking for.

In this particular case I'm using the `.Contains` method that allows me to have the flexibility needed to to do what you needed and it will take, whatever the value of the CLASS attribute is and use the string function Contains and search for the text `class1` at some point in the string.

The `p` is the content of the CLASS attribute (I used the name `p` but you could use anything you need and you don't have to declare it, is just a way to reference the attribute value, in this case a string) and as `p` is a string all functions available for strings are readily available to you, you can go as crazy as you want, like `.StartsWith` `.EndsWith`, `.ToUpper`, `.ToLower`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to point that out. I just edited the response to include a little bit extra detail, hope this helps anybody that comes searching for help.